# Woocommerce Tax Calculation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tax

South Africa's VAT just increased from 14% to 15% effective 1st April 2018.

We have increased the Standard Tax rate in the settings to 15% like so:
[image]

On the checkout page I'm adding a product worth R450 to the cart. It calculates to include VAT worth R58.70.

```
58.7 / 450 * 100 = 13
```

[image]

The Tax settings page looks as follows:

[image]

Is there a setting that is incorrectly set?

** EDIT **

I've tried to:

- Clear all transients
- Delete Tax calculations and re-enter them to no avail.

If I assume that the R58.70 is indeed 15%, I would arrive at a total of R391.33

What could the difference of R58.66 (R450 - R391.33) be?

Here are various VAT calculations based on different percentage values:

1. 12% - R48.21
2. 13% - R51.77
3. 14% - R55.26
4. 15% - R58.70
5. 16% - R62.07
6. 17% - R65.38
7. 18% - R68.64

Comment: Not sure can you please elaborate your problem what you want to achieve? Do you want to set up 450+tax?

Comment: Sure @VigneshPichamani . 15% of R450 should equal to 67.50 NOT 58.70

Comment: May be some sort of cache problem, try switching prices entered with tax - I mean change it, refresh the check out page, then revert the changes .

Comment: @BlessonChristy clearing transients doesnt work, neither does resetting the tax calculations. I made an edit to the original post.

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen can you try other rates like 13%, 14%, 15%, 16%... and see what values you are getting for each...

Comment: @Reigel added various calculations to the main post

Comment: The WooCommerce calculations are correct. To calculate VAT having the gross amount you should divide the gross amount by 1 + VAT percentage (i.e. if it is 15%, then you should divide by 1.15), then subtract the gross amount, multiply by -1 and round to the closest value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the calculation behind tax rate of both inclusive and exclusive.

From your settings you choosed **"Yes, I will enter prices inclusive of tax"** means you enter your price along with tax, so your overall price including tax will be **R450**

Let i describe the calculation behind exclusive and inclusive

**Exclusive Tax Calculation:**

```
$tax_rate = 15% => 15/100 => 0.15
$price = R450
$total_tax = 450*0.15 = R67.50(tax)
$total = $price+$total = 450+67.50 => R517.50
```

**Inclusive Tax Calculation**

As you set **yes i enter price inclusive of tax** and hence need to find the excluded tax price of **R450**

```
tax excluded price  = total item price / ((tax rate /100) + 1 );
```

You have to find the excluded tax amount first means

```
$tax_excluded_price = 450/(0.15+1) => R391.304347826(without round);
```

in this case you have to calculate the tax amount

```
$tax = $totalprice - $tax_excluded_price;

$tax = 450 - 391.304347826 => 58.695652174 => R58.70(round)

$totalprice = R450($tax_excluded_price+$tax);
```

As per your queries if you select **No, i will enter price exclusive of tax** then you can expect your result.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You just beat me to this answer, agreed the calculations are correct in WooCommerce for inclusive VAT @15%

Comment: Agreed. Thank you for this explanation.